# Shopify frontend React application on product page

Tags: reactjs, shopify

I have a small React application, that I want to run on every Cart-page of my Shopify store.
So far all I have found out is how to make a react-app for the Shopify admin, but I want it to be something the customer can interact with.

Additionally, the application needs the pictures of the product on which cart it currently is on.
How can I implement my react application like that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is broader and more open-ended than can reasonably be addressed in StackOverflow's Q&A format. Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Most good questions include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you can distill a single technical question with a minimal, reproducible example, you will likely get better results. Or try another forum -- certain social media, search engines, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some hours of research, I found an answer online that worked for me. It uses the App-Proxy option you have for Shopify applications.

This is the link where mert86 answered the question on the Shopify forum: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/How-to-render-HTML-in-my-theme-via-app-created-with-React/m-p/669730

Comment: Thanks for this. I just have one question: the "apps" and "subpath" that it requests for the proxy, where should I create that? Is this a folder with all my html/css/js?

Comment: @DiegoFortes I think you are right about that. But I am not 100% certain as I haven't worked on it for a couple of months now.

Comment: Hello! No problems, I figured it out. For anyone who comes across this thread: The "apps/subpath" is where it will show up on the `myshopify` store. So, for instance, if I add "apps/testing" it will show up on store.myshopify.com/apps/testing. Now, the ngrok URL is where I should create my html, css and JS & make them accessible via a REST API. This part is not mentioned in the Shopify Forum thread. After that you need to inject the new app page (`www.store.myshopify.com`) as a div or iframe to show up on every single page.